# How to iterate while for values in a dictionary?

Tags: python

I'm a new programmer. I need help with my code. In code, I have a dictionary that its values are a list. I want to do something in 'while' until the dictionary has a value. I used `while(len(migration))!= 0`, but it's not correct. How can I iterate while for all values in a dictionary? 
At the end of while, I want to delete values in the dictionary, but I don't know how can I do this and update my dictionary's values.

```py
migration_p = {2: [3, 4], 3: [3]}
def q_sequence():
    global p, sequence_q, r_s, d_s, d, partition, migration_p
    while len(migration_p) != 0:
        sequence_qi = []
        migration_pi = copy.deepcopy(migration_p)
        while len(migration_pi) != 0:
            tqi_min = math.inf
            for p in migration_pi.keys():
                # if len(migration_pi[p]) < M - A:
                for d in migration_pi[p]:
                    for r_src in migration_pi.keys():
                        if r_src not in sequence_qi:
                            xx = time_qi(d, p)[0]
                            if xx < tqi_min:
                                tqi_min = xx
                                r_s = r_src
                                d_s = d
            sequence_qi.append([(time_qi(d, p)[1], d_s), r_s])
            migration_pi = {p: d for p, d in migration_pi.items() if p != r_s}
            migration_pi = {p: d for p, d in migration_pi.items() if (p != r_s or d != d_s)}

        sequence_q.append(sequence_qi)
        # print(sequence_q)
        break

    return sequence_q
```

I expect the output to be `[[[(1, 3), 2], [(1, 3), 3]]]` but the actual output is `[[[(1, 3), 2], [(1, 3), 3], [(2, 4), 2]]]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To iterate on values

```
for value in dictionary.values():
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Would it help to know there's a built in way to iterate over all entries in a dictionary?

I can't remember exactly, but it is something to the effect of

```py
for key in nameOfDictionary:
    print(nameOfDictionary[key])
```

Then if after you did all of your iterative stuff, you could make it delete the dictionary by doing something like this.

```py
for key in nameOfDictionary:
    print(nameOfDictionary[key])
del nameOfDictionary
```

Optionally, if you want the dictionary to still exist, you can use nameOfDictionary.clear to simply remove all entries.

Answer (score 0):

do this to retrieve pair of key and value

```
for key, value in yourDictionary:
    print "this is key : "+key
    print "this is value : "+value
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for key in migration.keys():
    print "Key: " + key
    print "Value " + migration.pop(key) # This will delete the key from your dict and return a value
    migration[key] = new_value # This will create the key again and update it's value
```